# Condition to trigger sell variable only after buy variable is triggered

Tags: variables, pine-script, pine-script-v5, boolean-logic

I have two variables called buy and sell. I want the sell variable to be triggered or plotted only once after the buy  variable is triggered or plotted. the next time sell variable can alert or plot only when the next buy variable is alerted or plotted.

please can you help me with the code?

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

var strongbuytriggered = false
var bbrsellplotted = false

strongbuy = (close > ta.sma(close, 10)) and (ta.slope(close, 5) > 0)

bbrsell = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 20), ta.ema(close, 20))

alertcondition(strongbuy, title="A Strong Buy Signal", message="Strong buy")

alertcondition(condition=bbrsell, title="Sell Signal", message="Sell")

if strongbuy
    strongbuytriggered := true
    bbrsellplotted := false

if bbrsell and strongbuytriggered and not bbrsellplotted
    // Plot sell condition with yellow triangle
    plot_shape(triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.rgb(241, 124, 222), size=size.normal, title="Sell")
    bbrsellplotted := true

if not strongbuy
    strongbuytriggered := false
    bbrsellplotted := false
```